# How to replace default blogger template with a custom blogger theme

Tags: blogger

I want change the default blogger template to a more eye candy custom template. How do I go about this process (total newbie here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the template HTML.

1. Click the Design tab
2. Click "Edit HTML"
3. Check the "Expand Widget templates" checkbox
4. Copy the entire contents of the textbox into your favorite HTML editor
5. Edit to your heart's content
6. Paste back into the box (replacing the old content)
7. Click "Preview", if here are errors or visual problems, go to 4
8. Click "Save Template"

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

- Download the desired template file. xml file in this case.
- Go to blogger.com
- Select your blog.
- Click on template link.
  [image]
- Click on backup/restore button on top right corner.
- Click on 'choose file' button on the pop up.
- Select the xml file you downloaded in step 1
- Upload it. Now go to layout link. refer image of step 4.
- In the layout edit the section. remove unwanted widgets. add other widgets. drag and drop them. save settings. exit.